# How to set max file descriptors for a container?

Tags: ubuntu, elasticsearch, containers, ulimit

I want to run elasticsearch in a container (namely `nspawn`) and it requires the number of max file descriptors to be higher than the default 1024.

This is done, in the container, in the `systemd` service file appropriate for elasticsearch. This request upon service start is however not taken into account, the limit stays at 1024.

I then tried to change this limit on the command line within the container but I believe this is not possible (which is understandable):

```
root@elk:/etc/elasticsearch# ulimit -n 65536
-bash: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
```

**I believe that this limit should be either set, or allowed to be set, at the host level. Where should I set this up?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [bug report](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/4997) for `systemd` gave the solution. One needs to create or update `/etc/systemd/system/systemd-nspawn@.service.d/ulimit.conf` and add  `LimitNOFILE=infinity` in the `[Service]` section:

```
mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/systemd-nspawn@.service.d/
cat <<'EOF' >/etc/systemd/system/systemd-nspawn@.service.d/ulimit.conf
[Service]
LimitNOFILE=infinity
EOF
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl stop systemd-nspawn@CONTAINER
systemctl start systemd-nspawn@CONTAINER
```